# How to take any integer, for example 10050, and output it as $100.50?

Tags: c, printf

Example:

```
int amount = 10050;
printf("format_string", amount);
// What should the format string look like to get $100.50 as the output?
```

Is it possible to tell the `printf` function that I would like to have a dot placed two digits from the right without doing anything like this:

```
int amount = 10050;
printf("$%d.%02d", amount / 100, amount % 100); // Output: $100.50
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I added the *c* tag. If that's not it, edit to add the correct language tag.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything wrong with that. I'm just asking if there is possibly a shorter way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert it to `float`, divide by 100, and print it with a float format.

```
printf("$%.2f", ((double)amount)/100);
```

Comment: should that be 100.0?

Comment: @pm100: only one of the operands of the division needs to be a floating point type.

Comment: Not if `amount` is typecast to float.  But you could write alternately `amount/100.0` (which might be easier to read).

Comment: @par I could write that, but I think my version makes the intent clearer.

Comment: I am always paranoid - integer always seems to win

Comment: @Barmar styles obviously vary.  +1 to you.

Comment: `%f` is actually a `double` format, so you might as well convert to `double`. But you could get rounding errors for large values. The method the OP uses in the question is better.

Comment: @KeithThompson Agree with converting to double. I don't think there are any architectures where the size of int is large enough that there would be rounding errors after converting to double.

Comment: Rounding errors (with the initial float version of this code) start at 13107201 (on my machine).

Comment: If `int` is 32 bits, and `double` has a 53-bit mantissa, I wonder why you would lose precision so low.

Comment: @Barmar this was with the version of the code that uses floats instead of double.

Comment: @PaulHankin That makes sense. This is why double is better for this.

Comment: @Barmar: In fact there are, though they're probably not common. I've worked on systems (Cray vector systems) where both `int` and `double` are 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in function:

```
void printmoney (int amount) {
    printf("$%d.%02d", amount / 100, amount % 100); // Output: $100.50
}
```

Then you call it just as:

```
printmoney(10050); // Output: $100.50
```

Comment: `printmoney(-123)` --> "$-1.-23"